# Transformar um valor de uma variável em um paragrafo

Tags: javascript, dom

Quero saber como faço pra, ao invés de mandar o resultado da função pro alert, criar um parágrafo, por exemplo. Lembrando que essa dúvida é pra me ajudar com projetos futuros, por isso estou colocando um código bem simples.

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" lang="pt-br">
    <title>Formulário teste</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enviar(){
            var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

            var nome2 = formulario.nome.value;
            alert(nome2);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dados para cadastro</h1>

    <form id="formulario">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input id="nom" type="nome" name="nome">

        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
        <input type="cpf" name="cpf">

        <label for="cep">CEP</label>
        <input type="cep" name="cep">

        <button onclick="enviar()">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h1 id="receber"></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como assim? Não ficou claro

Comment: Ao invés de alertar o valor do input, enviar para um paragrafo no HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse exemplo a tag h1 vai receber o conteúdo da variável só quando for acionada a função enviar, se deseja antes disso é só retirar o código da função e colocar em outra, aí terá varias opções para chamar a função até mesmo automaticamente quando a página acabar de ser carregada. Exemplo 2.

Exemplo 1

```
<h1 id="receber"></h1>  

<script>
    function enviar(){
        var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

        var nome2 = formulario.nome.value;
        //alert(nome2);
       document.getElementById( 'receber' ).innerHTML = nome2;
    }
</script>
```

Exemplo 2

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function () {
    document.getElementById( 'receber' ).innerHTML = nome2;
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado Hugo! Dessa forma fica mais fácil até pra poder estilizar o html.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar [document.createElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp). Mas adicione o atributo `type="button"` ao botão <kbd>submit</kbd> para que a página não seja recarregada. Veja exemplo comentado:

```js
function enviar(){
   var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
  
   var nome2 = formulario.nome.value;
   var paragrafo = document.createElement("p"); // crio o elemento <p>
   var texto = document.createTextNode(nome2); // defino o texto
   paragrafo.appendChild(texto); // insiro o texto no elemento <p>
   document.body.appendChild(paragrafo); // insiro na página
}
```

```html
<h1>Dados para cadastro</h1>

 <form id="formulario">
     <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
     <input id="nom" type="nome" name="nome">

     <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
     <input type="cpf" name="cpf">

     <label for="cep">CEP</label>
     <input type="cep" name="cep">

     <button onclick="enviar()" type="button">Submit</button>
 </form>

 <h1 id="receber"></h1>
```

Comment: Ah, pocha. Muito obrigado!